# Run ant script when project in OpenEdge Developer Studio (eclipse) project is opened

Tags: eclipse, ant, project, openedge

I'm using Progress Developer Studio (PDS) from OpenEdge, which is an Eclipse instance.

I've added ANT plugin to PDS, and I would like to automatically run an ANT target when I open a OpenEdge project, and also when I start PDS with a project already opened.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Many thanks!

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Eclipse has such an option.

But you could create an _idestartup.p in a project root and OS-COMMAND the Ant Script.